# How to search a key value pair inside a json object using typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using typeorm to manage my postgresql database in nestjs. I had to save a json response in the db, so I saved whole response under one column. This is my entity.

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity,  PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({name:'travel_bookings'})

export class TravelBookings {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column('uuid')
    userId:string;

    @Column({ type: 'json' })
    booking_response: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    Status:string;

    
    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' }) 'created_at': Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' }) 'updated_at': Date;    
}

`
```

The booking_response is a long json data, in which there is one id. Now I am creating a function to update Status where the id inside the json matches with the id I provide.
This is one example json response -

```json
{"type":"flight-order","id":"eJzTd9f397V09w8FAAs4AmY%3D","queuingOfficeId":"NCE4D31SB","associatedRecords":[{"reference":"OM9GOU","creationDate":"2023-02-07T11:40:00.000","originSystemCode":"GDS","flightOfferId":"1"}],"flightOffers":[{"type":"flight-offer","id":"1","source":"GDS","nonHomogeneous":false,"lastTicketingDate":"2023-02-08","itineraries":[{"segments":[{"departure":{"iataCode":"BOS","terminal":"C","at":"2023-03-10T22:55:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"LIS","terminal":"1","at":"2023-03-11T10:20:00"},"carrierCode":"TP","number":"216","aircraft":{"code":"32Q"},"duration":"PT6H25M","id":"9","numberOfStops":0,"co2Emissions":[{"weight":303,"weightUnit":"KG","cabin":"ECONOMY"}]},{"departure":{"iataCode":"LIS","terminal":"1","at":"2023-03-11T11:45:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"MAD","terminal":"2","at":"2023-03-11T14:05:00"},"carrierCode":"TP","number":"1014","aircraft":{"code":"32Q"},"duration":"PT1H20M","id":"10","numberOfStops":0,"co2Emissions":[{"weight":68,"weightUnit":"KG","cabin":"ECONOMY"}]}]},{"segments":[{"departure":{"iataCode":"MAD","terminal":"2","at":"2023-03-11T21:10:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"LIS","terminal":"1","at":"2023-03-11T21:30:00"},"carrierCode":"TP","number":"1019","aircraft":{"code":"321"},"duration":"PT1H20M","id":"83","numberOfStops":0,"co2Emissions":[{"weight":68,"weightUnit":"KG","cabin":"ECONOMY"}]},{"departure":{"iataCode":"LIS","terminal":"1","at":"2023-03-12T11:40:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"BOS","terminal":"E","at":"2023-03-12T15:20:00"},"carrierCode":"TP","number":"217","aircraft":{"code":"32Q"},"duration":"PT7H40M","id":"84","numberOfStops":0,"co2Emissions":[{"weight":303,"weightUnit":"KG","cabin":"ECONOMY"}]}]}],"price":{"currency":"USD","total":"613.85","base":"184.00","fees":[{"amount":"0.00","type":"TICKETING"},{"amount":"0.00","type":"SUPPLIER"},{"amount":"0.00","type":"FORM_OF_PAYMENT"}],"grandTotal":"613.85","billingCurrency":"USD"},"pricingOptions":{"fareType":["PUBLISHED"],"includedCheckedBagsOnly":false},"validatingAirlineCodes":["TP"],"travelerPricings":[{"travelerId":"1","fareOption":"STANDARD","travelerType":"ADULT","price":{"currency":"USD","total":"613.85","base":"184.00","taxes":[{"amount":"5.60","code":"AY"},{"amount":"4.40","code":"J9"},{"amount":"15.80","code":"JD"},{"amount":"0.70","code":"OG"},{"amount":"16.10","code":"PT"},{"amount":"3.60","code":"QV"},{"amount":"42.20","code":"US"},{"amount":"3.83","code":"XA"},{"amount":"4.50","code":"XF"},{"amount":"7.00","code":"XY"},{"amount":"6.52","code":"YC"},{"amount":"27.60","code":"YP"},{"amount":"292.00","code":"YQ"}],"refundableTaxes":"86.75"},"fareDetailsBySegment":[{"segmentId":"9","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"UUSDSI0E","brandedFare":"DISCOUNT","class":"U","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":0}},{"segmentId":"10","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"UUSDSI0E","brandedFare":"DISCOUNT","class":"U","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":0}},{"segmentId":"83","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"UUSDSI0E","brandedFare":"DISCOUNT","class":"U","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":0}},{"segmentId":"84","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"UUSDSI0E","brandedFare":"DISCOUNT","class":"U","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":0}}]}]}],"travelers":[{"id":"1","dateOfBirth":"1982-01-16","gender":"MALE","name":{"firstName":"JORGE","lastName":"GONZALES"},"documents":[{"number":"00000000","issuanceDate":"2015-04-14","expiryDate":"2025-04-14","issuanceCountry":"ES","issuanceLocation":"Madrid","nationality":"ES","birthPlace":"Madrid","documentType":"PASSPORT","holder":true}],"contact":{"purpose":"STANDARD","phones":[{"deviceType":"MOBILE","countryCallingCode":"34","number":"480080076"}],"emailAddress":"jorge.gonzales833@telefonica.es"}}],"remarks":{"general":[{"subType":"GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS","text":"ONLINE BOOKING FROM INCREIBLE VIAJES"}]},"ticketingAgreement":{"option":"DELAY_TO_CANCEL","delay":"6D"},"automatedProcess":[{"code":"IMMEDIATE","queue":{"number":"0","category":"0"},"officeId":"NCE4D31SB"}],"contacts":[{"addresseeName":{"firstName":"PABLO RODRIGUEZ"},"address":{"lines":["Calle Prado, 16"],"postalCode":"28014","countryCode":"ES","cityName":"Madrid"},"purpose":"STANDARD","phones":[{"deviceType":"LANDLINE","countryCallingCode":"34","number":"480080071"},{"deviceType":"MOBILE","countryCallingCode":"33","number":"480080072"}],"companyName":"INCREIBLE VIAJES","emailAddress":"support@increibleviajes.es"}]}
```

This is my function -

```
 async flightCancel(data) {

    var amadeus = await new Amadeus({
      clientId: process.env.API_KEY,
      clientSecret: process.env.API_SECRET
    });
    // const output=await this.travelBookingsRepo.findOne({where:{ booking_response:"eJzTd9f397V09w8FAAs4AmY%3D"}})
    // console.log(output);
    this.travelBookingsRepo.update({ booking_response: { id: data } },{Status:'Cancelled'})
    return amadeus.booking.flightOrder(data).delete();
  }
```

I found some solutions on web using entityManager , getManager/getConnection but these are deprecated and work no more. If issue is about update function, then I have tried it with findOne and save methods too but still unsuccessful. Please help me in resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using after typeorm@0.3.0, you can not use entityManager , getManager/getConnection.
Instead you could use 'DataSource'

You could check my [github](https://github.com/Alex-Choi0/NestJS_useRawQuery_TypeORM.git).

Comment: check the file 'src/users/users.service.ts' line 14 and 18